# using dynamically generated anchor tags in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

i'm generating some anchor tags dynamically and use them to redirect to other page by using their id's. I've done it through inline scripts many times but unfortunately chrome extensions doesn't supports inline scripts.

`var profileUid` is generated dynamically and i make them as id's to anchor tag each time
`<a id='+profileUid+'>'link</a>` so each link have different id's, when i click these links that should call following function
`$(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            alert(this.id);
            chrome.tabs.create({url:'https://plus.google.com/'+this.id+'/posts'});
        });`
to redirect to new pages, it works fine with static elements(anchor tags) but not for dynamically generated elements. this is driving me insane, let me get some help to get out of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `$('a').click(handler);`, it first finds all matching elements, and then binds to their events. So, it only works for elements already existing at the time of invocation.

So, when you later add an `<a>` element to the DOM, you need to take care of its events separately.

```
function handler() {/* ... */}

// Bind to static elements
$(function() {
  $('a').click(handler);
});

// Create an elemet
var element = $('<a>');
element.attr('id', profileUid);
element.text("Whatever");
element.click(handler);
element.appendTo(parent);
```

Comment: hi Xan, thanks for the answer but could you please explain why we are appending it to parent `element.appendTo(parent);` anyway it works fine without it but when i use that function it throwing an error<br>`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined jquery.js:5249
createSafeFragment jquery.js:5249
jQuery.extend.buildFragment jquery.js:5520
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:5885
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery.js:5704
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.js:5962
(anonymous function)`

Comment: I'm just illustrating how to insert a node built with jQuery into the document (one of the ways, in any case). No idea about your error, are you using the latest jQuery?

Comment: im using jquery 1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Consider updating; the latest 1.x branch release is 1.11.1, and latest overall is 2.1.1

Comment: Also, I think the error is unrelated to what's in my code.